# java doesn't work and page is blocked from downloading

Tags: windows-7

I can't download Java. I think I have a Windows 7 PC. It is a 6-7 year old machine.
What should I do? How can I get Java so that I can start playing again? Is there an online tutorial available?

Comment: Please don't shout. All-caps is hard to read and hard to fix.

Comment: Come back when you can tell us what version of Windows you have.  If http://java.com/en/download/win8.jsp?locale=en is blocked you are out of luck

Comment: i have windows 7 PC

Comment: You are going to have to accurately describe what happens when you try to download Java.  Where do you go to download it, what happens when you do, and what errors you see.  Without these things this question is simply too vague.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the page is having an issue right now. You have nothing to worry about your PC.It may be a problem with their servers.

You can get it from [this](http://www.oldapps.com/java.php) link for now.

Comment: Upvoted because whether or not the original question was clear and complete, your answer is correct -- there is an issue with the download page right at this point. IMO, that was a nice little catch.